# If the truncation function provides differential privacy

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

We have values in the range $[a, b]$, and we apply a differential privacy mechanism to add noise to these values. After obtaining the noisy values, we employ the following truncation function: if a noisy value falls below $a$, it is truncated to $a$, and if the noisy value exceeds $b$, it is truncated to $b$. Does this truncation function ensure differential privacy, assuming that the mechanism itself provides differential privacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean, namely

1. does it *maintain* the level of differential privacy one gets from adding noise, or
2. does it *enhance* the level of differential privacy one gets.

The answer to the first question is "trivially yes".
This is because differential privacy satisfies a "data-processing inequality", in the sense that if a mechanism $M(x)$ satisfies some notion of differential privacy, then $f(M(x))$ does as well, for any function $f$.

There are certain situations where one can show that natural $f$ *enhance* the level of differential privacy. This is generally called "privacy amplification". I don't know if clamping does, but don't see why it would.
But various other types of post-processing (for example sub-sampling) do enhance the level of differential privacy one obtains.